# Using Python for testing non-python code

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, fortran, fortran90

We are developing a numerical simulation program in FORTRAN90 (procedural, not OO and unfortunately some COMMON blocks are present but no GOTO's :-) ) and are thinking of using Python to help us in unit-testing (retroactively) and verification testing. We would like to set up a testing environment in Python to a) do unit-testing and b) do verification testing (i.e. run small test cases with well-known solutions). We would like to be able to group different tests together (by FORTRAN90 procedure for unit-testing or by problem topic for verification testing) and allow tests to be run either individually or by group.

The simulation program is text-input/output based, so we could come up with some input files to be run and compared to verified output files. For unit testing, however, I guess we will probably need to write wrappers for each FORTRAN90 subroutine.

Has anybody been in a likewise situation before? What tips can you give us?

thanks.

(btw rewriting the FORTRAN90 code in Python is not (yet) an option)

Comment: Did you try [f2py](http://www.f2py.com/)?

Comment: Why not use `bash` scripts to run it?

Comment: You could also define your own testsuite using GNU Autotools. (I never tried this for myself...)

Comment: As an alternative, you could look at a unit testing framework designed for Fortran, such as [FRUIT](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fortranxunit/index.php?title=FruitExample).

Comment: Python is not a bad choice here. Having used pfUnit and FRUIT, I'd say the Fortran unit testing frameworks are not very well developed compared to those in other languages, and python has the advantage of being easy to use, flexible, and platform neutral.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "os.system()" function, this can be used to call linux/unix commands from the python script directly.  You can also use the "subprocess" module.

Use it like this:

os.system("ls -G")

This will call 'ls -G' from python just like if you were calling it yourself.  You can easily compile and call fortran code using this command as well.  Or, if you're familiar with bash scripting, you could use that as a wrapper for your unit testing as well.  The scientific computing community seems to like perl for these types of tasks, but python should work just fine.

At least you're working with fortran90 and not fortran77.  Those goto statements can make debugging a code excessively interesting. :P

Comment: In general, isn't the `subprocess` module [preferred](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) over `os.system()` these days?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that provides some insight into how you can go about with your task :

[Calling Fortran from Python](http://www.sfu.ca/~mawerder/notes/calling_fortran_from_python.html)

This link also provides references to two modules -**f2py** and **fwrap**. The link for **f2py** seems to be broken, hence you can refer to **f2py** documentation [here](http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/)

Comment: My only issue with using f2py is that the OP might have to modify their code to get it to compile with f2py, when all they want is a unit testing framework.